# dividing a number by the day of month only returning single digit number

Tags: php, division

I am trying to calculate what pace our sales team in on for the month, but when I divide our numbers so far (17,305) by the day of the month (08), I am getting the wrong number (2.125).

I've tried converting the date from a string to a number, but I everything I read says php should know how to handle the numbers when it's a string or number.

```
$dateday = date('d');
$numberofdays = date('t');

echo $ztmmoney.' total for month<br>'; 
echo $dateday.' day of the month<br>';
$mavg = $ztmmoney/$dateday;
echo $mavg.' daily average<br>';
echo $numberofdays.' days in month<br>';
$pace = $mavg * $numberofdays;

echo 'on pace for: '.$pace;
```

I should see 17,305/8 = 2,163.125

but this is my output:

17,305 total for month

08 day of the month

2.125 daily average

31 days in month

on pace for: 65.875

Comment: Numbers don't have commas (unless your locale uses it for a decimal), in either case `17,305` becomes `17`.  `17 / 8 = 2.125`

Comment: Don't use `number_format` before your calculations, use it after.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this to get rid of the wrong calculation

```
$ztmmoney = '17,305';
$ztmmoney = intval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $ztmmoney));
```

Comment: What if `$ztmmoney` isn't supposed to be an integer? `17,305.99`

Comment: @AbraCadaver are you doing calculations from string by dividing them or any other mathematical operation?

Comment: I'm not doing anything, just commenting.

Comment: @AbraCadaver OP clearly stated that he has the values like 17,305 and my solution is giving the correct result

Comment: I'm sure `$ztmmoney` is always `17,305` ;-)

Comment: yes, sorry$ztmoney is a result of  $ztmoney = number_format($ztmoney); Thanks!

Comment: Don't use this.  Don't `number_format` before calculation.

Comment: @AbraCadaver please suggest a better solution

Comment: Just like I said _DON'T `number_format` before calculation_! Why use `number_format` to add formatting and then `preg_replace` to get rid of the formatting???

Comment: @AbraCadaver let's say this formatted data is coming from an API, what solution you are going to provide?

Comment: Read the comments dude **yes, sorry$ztmoney is a result of $ztmoney = number_format($ztmoney); Thanks!**

Comment: @AbraCadaver I understand this, I am asking a normal question what if it comes from an API?

Comment: I didn't number_format before the calc, I was just reusing a variable higher up in my code that I had converted to number_format. So using the preg_replace worked, but I was also able to just use the original variable with the raw value. Thanks both!